# What is the difference between the javascript errors "Cannot read property 'foo' of null" and "null is not an object"

Tags: javascript, error-handling, typeerror

We're logging javascript errors and one error message that has come up a lot is `null is not an object`, for example `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'foo[bar]')`. In my searches about this error and trying to replicate the error, I continually get a `Cannot read property 'foo' of null` error instead. I cannot figure out a way to do something that results in a `null is not an object` error.

What is the difference between the two errors and what are some examples for when one would get called instead of the other?

Comment: AFAIK particular error messages depends on the current JS environment (browser)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One example [is here](http://jsbin.com/qimerepode/edit?html,js,console,output)

When you assign null value to an object and try to access any of it's properties you will get null is not an object.

So, basically if you will try to call any function on an object that has null value will give this error:

- > null is not an object in Safari
- > Cannot read property of null in Chrome
- > TypeError: obj[1] is null in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

The reply by hindmost is correct, there are different messages depending on the browser. Given the following code:

```
var a = null, b = 5;
a[b];
```

Chrome will give the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '5' of null` while Safari will give the error `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'a[b]')`.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference. The message depends on the browser/environment your script is running on.Eg:-

```
var x = null;
console.log(x.length);
```

for chrome the message would be

```
cannot read property 'length' of null
```

for safari

```
'null' is not an object (evaluating 'c.length')
```